# How to get specific percentile spans of a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a dataframe that contains information about citizens of a city including their income. I want to break the income to percentiles top 1%, next 4%, next 15%, next 20% and the last 50% and for each percentile to compute how many citizens lie in this percentile, mean, sum of their income etc etc..

I know how to find percentiles using the numpy.percentile method but I cannot figure out for example how to find the 4% between top 1% and the rest 95%

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the percentiles and filtering your dataframe? Try for example this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dummy list of values and dataframe
vals = list(np.arange(100_001))
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=["income"])

# filter on percentiles
df_4percent = df[(df.values_ > np.percentile(df.income, 1)) & (df.values_ < np.percentile(df.income, 5))]
```

Comment: I don't understand how you choose the percentiles, are you sure that it is np.percentile(df, 1)) and not for example np.percentile(df.values_, 1)) because I want the top 1% of the income column and so on

Comment: @Er1Hall In this dummy example it doesn't make a difference because there only is one data column. But yes – if you want to calculate on a specific column you need to specify that. I have corrected my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You want [`pd.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html):

```
pd.qcut(df['income'], [0,.5,.6,.8, .95, .99,1])
```

will give you cuts in the corresponding buckets, which you can pass to `groupby`.